# How do I skip every other Row in a matrix.rows.count function?

Tags: matrix, count, rows, skip

```
Set matrix = Range("crise")

For i = 2 To matrix.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To matrix.Columns.Count
```

The code is used to convert a matrix (month/salesrep.) from sales into comissions to pay.
Due to a crisis commissions shall be payed every other month. the rows 1,3,5,...must equal 0

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 2 To matrix.Rows.Count Step 2
```

or you could increment i at the end of the loop

```
i++;
next;

i = i + 1
next
```